# Coloring ham green

Tags: presentation, ham

It has come to my attention that in the book "Green Eggs and Ham", the property "green" is applied to both the eggs and the ham. How can I achieve this effect (green ham) at home? I have years of green eggs + normal ham to make up for ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I did this as a kid with my mom, we just put food dye (the same we put in the eggs) on the slices of ham.

As someone who has tried this though, I have to **strongly** recommend you don't. While it's easy to get around the fact that the eggs you're about to eat are green, ham that's green just doesn't look right. It was a struggle to eat it even though I knew it was only food coloring.

My dad wouldn't even touch it because it looked so wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I cannot guarantee the following will be tasty or edible...

My first thought would be a brine of some some sort. I imagine that should turn your ham green, by soaking it in a quick brine. I've heard of people brining hams, so if you do a google for that, that might be a place to start and add food coloring to it. However, like many brines/marinades, it might not soak all the way through... So I don't know if you'd pre-slice the pieces or what...

Or perhaps, even simpler you could just "paint" your ham after cooking...

Comment: something with parsley maybe?

Comment: Kool-Aid comes to mind for the brine coloring here. It works well with pickles, why not ham too? http://www.google.com/search?q=kool-aid+pickles&num=20&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=Yaz&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&prmd=imvnse&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=PXRRT_3eGIaMsAKb7fHvBQ&ved=0CDoQsAQ&biw=1402&bih=931